# wkhtmltopdf codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, wkhtmltopdf

wkhtmltopdf sounds like an excellent solution...the problem is nothing happens on the exec

shell_exec("c:\wkhtmltopdf.exe","http://www.google.com google.pdf");

Am i doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Can you use the "official" class?

http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/wiki/IntegrationWithPhp

If not, perhaps peeking into how they did things will help you out with your implementation.

```
// Include WKPDF class.
require_once('wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf.php');

// Create PDF object.
$pdf = new WKPDF();
// Set PDF's HTML
$pdf->set_html('Hello <b>Mars<.b>!');
// Convert HTML to PDF
$pdf->render();
// Output PDF. The file name is suggested to the browser.
$pdf->output(WKPDF::$PDF_EMBEDDED, 'sample.pdf');
```

**Edit:**

New link, from the Githubs - https://github.com/mikehaertl/phpwkhtmltopdf

Comment: any sample example with the class?

Comment: @Bart `page not found`. Maybe you would want to update the answer!

Comment: can any one send me link to download 'wkhtmltopdf.php' file @Bart

Answer (score 0):

shell_exec() only takes one parameter, but you have given it two. Try this instead:

```
shell_exec("c:\wkhtmltopdf.exe http://www.google.com google.pdf");
```

I think that will do it. You might also consider using the `exec()` function.

Answer (score 0):

add path to wkhtmltopdf.exe CLASS_PATH variable 
and in your php script use bellow code

passthru("wkhtmltopdf www.gmail.com output.pdf",$err);

// We'll be outputting a PDF
header('Content-type: application/pdf');

// It will be called downloaded.pdf
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="output.pdf"');

// The PDF source is in original.pdf
readfile('output.pdf');

i hope this will work...