# wkhtmltopdf integration with codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, pdf, wkhtmltopdf

How to integrated this pdf library : [Wkhtmltopdf](https://github.com/mikehaertl/phpwkhtmltopdf)

with codeigniter app ?

I was using TCPDF, not so good, because I can not modify html propterties with javascript or jquery...

Oke, You know, if U wanna using TCPDF in CI, YOu must download TCPDF and put those TCPDF's folder to library for example. 
And then, you make a file to extends the head class of TCPDF like

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

    require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/tcpdf/tcpdf.php';

    class TC_Pdf extends TCPDF
    {
    }
```

Okey. Now if I wanna using Wkhtmltopdf, what I am suppose to do ?

Comment: Please post code example with your question is there any issues?

Comment: Please try this link here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3474810/wkhtmltopdf-codeigniter and this http://www.ahowto.net/php/easily-integrate-mpdf-into-codeigniter-framework/